# tinymce is not working in php?

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

I am new to tinymce editor. According to the website their installation is very easy and it works as well. But when receiving in php. It gets incomplete codes

This is html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $('textarea').tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : 'http://localhost/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

        // General options
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
   });
</script>
```

the textarea is

```
<textarea id="f_page_body" name="f_page_body" class="tinymice"></textarea>
```

php code is

```
$body = $_POST["f_page_body"];


        echo(stripslashes($body));
```

In editor it looks fine but when displaying in php it just get in complete code like following

```
 <p><span  xx-large; font-family: impact,chicago; color: #99cc00;">I am testing it</span></p>
```

Comment: Is that all you do to the `f_page_body `POST value before outputting? I think the problem at hand is obvious, but I think unless there's more you're doing we're seeing, it's somehow a TinyMCE problem, not PHP.

Comment: In that case, it's either what was sent originally to TinyMCE (which could be broken, but we don't have that to review), or mostly likely, TinyMCE is munging the markup before it is sent in the POST. Try setting up a test page elsewhere with new code and see if, with a simple setup, it works, then add back each customized/advanced add-on technique until you find the problem, or it works and you can transfer it to the original location you have now.

Comment: i strongly advice all tinymce users not to use the jquery tinymce build because it is a source of trouble and slow when it comes to keyboard input handling.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the **style="font-size:** part for the span that displays the TinyMCE editor?  It looks like it gets cut off somehow.

Your HTML:

```
<p><span  xx-large; font-family: impact,chicago; color: #99cc00;">I am testing it</span></p>
```

What is should be:

```
<p><span style="font-size: xx-large; font-family: impact,chicago; color: #99cc00;">I am testing it</span></p>
```